# Can i sue Cash App for not paying up on the invite a friend referral bonus?

Tags: contract-law

Cash app is offering a promotion where the invited gets $5 and the person who invited the friend (me) is supposed to get $30. Well I invited my mother in law and we did everything necessary to get the bonus. In fact, she did receive the $5 bonus. But they will not pay up the $30. And they will not give a reason why. I have chatted with 3 of 4 different people and they all say the same thing (there is no call center) they just send me this:

"To receive an invitation bonus, an invited friend must:

- Be new to Cash App with no previous accounts
- Enter their invite code correctly within 7 days of sending/receiving their first payment
- Link a personal debit card not associated with another Cash App account
- Send $5 or more, either as a single payment or multiple smaller payments, within 14 days of entering the invite code"

Which we did all of those things. Obviously, otherwise my mother in law would not have gotten the referral bonus, either. However, she did get the bonus. They're just choosing not to give it to me.

Do I have a reasonable case here, or not?

Comment: Given the price of gas, are you sure it's even worth driving to the court house for $30?

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Sometimes litigation is not about money, even if formally claimed so.

Comment: Did you read all the fine print **when** the bonus is to be paid? Often, those have very specific retention clauses or how often someone can get it. Or to qualify themselves. In any case: litigating this will cost **thousands**.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have a reasonable case here, or not?

Yes. Your description meets the elements of the formation of a contract: The company made a *general offer* (similarly, *unilateral contract*), and you performed by getting them a new client.

The fact that the company has performed part of its promise does not release it from its obligation of full performance.

This matter would have to be litigated in Small Claims court or the jurisdictional equivalent of your location unless the terms of the offer specify a different forum or dispute resolution method.